New to Linux development: any good resources describing the administration of the environment to run my program?
New to Ubuntu Desktop 22.04, and am wanting to run a .NET 6 program that I've created on Windows on the system. Some basic tests have shown the program works - in a way. I can run it via the dotnet command, and I have a .NET 6 SDK installed. If I launch via sudo, it even logs in the /var/log hierarchy.
But I know there's more involved in actually making this more "production-like". Things like I want to know how to configure my system so that the program runs when the system launches, my program is able to log under /var/log WITHOUT running it via sudo, etc. I guess it's part systems administration, part understanding the Linux/UNIX environment better, etc. And I haven't tried to get at other ports, like USB. Right now things are being done on a mini PC device that has some resources, but there's a longer term goal to see about targeting something smaller like a Raspberry Pi. But let's ignore that for now.
Is there some sort of "Linux Dev for Dummies" resource(s) that will let me become more familiar with how things really work when someone who know how to set up a system is in charge?

You can start with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop: Applications and Administration which is free to read online. "Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop: Applications and Administration" is a guide designed for users of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop. It covers both using the applications that come with Ubuntu and administering the system itself.
My Google Books has a hyperlink that says "Back to classic Google Books" because I opted in to use the upgraded Google Books web app instead of classic Google Books. In the top left corner, you'll see a button that says "Try it now." Click that to switch to the upgraded  interface. This upgraded interface lets you search for a keyword or phrase like a chapter title and then it displays sections of several pages that contain this phrase. Click a section and then it jumps straight to that page.
Ubuntu Documentation

Ubuntu documentation for Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server



Release
Desktop
Server




Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
HTML
HTML and PDF


Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
HTML
HTML and PDF


Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)
HTML
PDF (Archive link)



Starting with 20.04, the server guide is now a common document published at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs based on corresponding posts in Ubuntu Discourse.

Ubuntu Community Help Wiki has useful wikis for new Ubuntu users.



Thanks for that reference. It looks pretty interesting, though some of the sections that might be of most interest are the ones not included in the preview. I'll peruse over the weekend.

My Google Books has a hyperlink that says "Back to classic Google Books" because I opted in to use the upgraded Google Books web app instead of classic Google Books. This upgraded app lets you search for a keyword or phrase like a chapter title and then it displays sections of several pages that contain this phrase. Click a section and then it jumps straight to that page.
